# Is there a way to use the --forcerun functionality in snakemake programmatically?

Tags: api, snakemake

For one project I need to switch some arguments of snakemake functionality inside the snakemake code. For example, I have snakemake code as follows:

```
configfile: srcdir('config.yaml') 

if config['run_from_first'] == 1:
    # TODO 
    # add here some code that will force run 'first_rule' even when the output is already computed 

rule first_rule:
    input: a.txt
    output: b.txt
    run: ....

rule second_rule:
    input: b.txt
    output: c.txt
    run: ....
```

When the file `b.txt` if already computed, I can easily redo the computation of it by appending `--forcerun first_rule` (or `--forcerun b.txt`) to snakemake command as:

```
snakemake --forcerun first_rule
```

It is possible to do this inside the snakefile (i.e. finishing the `# TODO` code) so there is no need to change snakemake call, but just change the `config.yaml` file?

Comment: Yes -- using standard python, test whether `b.txt` exists, and delete it if it does.

Comment: this does not cover all situations - for example --dry-run (here it would delete b.txt and not recreate it)